# VHDL: How to use 2 regular 4-Bit adders to design an 8-Bit BCD counter?

Tags: vhdl

Unlike most counters that i have viewed on this website, my BCD counter requires the use of two 4-Bit adders in order to make 1 8-Bit BCD counter. What I have done so far is design a regular full adder, used that to design a regular 4 bit adder.

This is my code so far:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity adder8b_custom is
port(
    X: in std_logic_vector( 7 downto 0);
    Y: in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    S: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));
end adder8b_custom;

architecture adder8b_custom of adder8b_custom is

component adder4b 
    port (    X :   in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);   
          Y :   in STD_LOGIC_vector (3 downto 0);   
          C0: in STD_LOGIC; 
          S :    out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0); 
          C4: out STD_LOGIC);
end component;

signal s1:std_logic_vector ( 7 downto 0); --for addition
signal s2:std_logic_vector ( 7 downto 0); --for subtraction
signal s3, s4, s5, s6: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);--placeholders
signal i, j, k, l: std_logic;

begin 
    u1: adder4b port map (X => X (3 downto 0), Y => "0001",c0=>'0', S => s3 (3 downto 0), c4=>i);
    s1(3 downto 0) <=s3(3 downto 0) when s3 (3 downto 0) /="1010"
    else "0000";
    s<=s1;
    --u2: adder4b port map (X => X (7 downto 4), Y => "0001" ,c0 => i, S => s4 (3 downto 0), c4=>j);
    --s1( 7 downto 4) <= s4( 3 downto 0) when s4( 3 downto 0) /= "1010"
    --else "0000";
    --s(7 downto 4)<= s1;
end;
```

As you can see, everything after the signals is messed up and i do know know how to fix it.

I appreciate all input.

Answer (score 0):

If your 4bit adder is working correctly you just need to map carry out from the low nibble to the carry in of the high nibble.  Then map your 8bit respectively.

It's been too long since I played with VHDL so I can remember the code you need.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that was exactly what i was thinking! The problem though is the same as yours: I am bad with the language. I was just wondering if somebody could solve this for me in code. Thanks for your input Matthew!